# ExtJS Datefield TypeError j[d] is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-grid, extjs7

I have a grid in extjs 7.2 with a store that is filtered by date. I have a start date and an end date, which are bound to date objects in my ViewModel. When the grid is initialized, the date for the first field (start_date) shows up in the field, but then the program throws a type error from the datefield.

> Uncaught TypeError: j[d] is not a function
>
> ```
> ExtJS 86
>
>     getErrors
>     getErrors
>     validateValue
>     isValid
>     validate
>     onChange
>     onChange
>     checkChange
>     setValue
>     setValue
>     setValue
>     setValue
>     onBindNotify
>     notify
>     react
>     notify
>     notify
>     fireItemMutationEvent
>     clip
>     setViewSize
>     onViewResize
>     onViewRefresh
>     pass
>     createSingle
>     fire
>     doFireEvent
>     doFireEvent
>     doFireEvent
>     fireEventArgs
>     fireEvent
>     onBoxReady
>     afterFirstLayout
>     afterFirstLayout
>     afterComponentLayout
>     afterComponentLayout
>     notifyOwner
>     callLayout
>     flushLayouts
>     runComplete
>     k
>     callParent
>     runComplete
>     run
>     flushLayouts
>     resumeLayouts
>     resumeLayouts
>     setActiveTab
>     doActivateTab
>     onClick
>     fire
>     fire
>     publish
>     publishDelegatedDomEvent
>     doDelegatedEvent
>     onDelegatedEvent
>     addDelegatedListener
>     subscribe
>     addListener
>     addListener
>     doAddListener
>     doAddListener
>     addManagedListener
>     addManagedListener
>     a
>     onRender
>     onRender
>     finishRender
>     finishRenderItems
>     finishRender
>     finishRenderChildren
>     afterRender
>     finishRender
>     finishRenderItems
>     finishRender
>     finishRenderChildren
>     finishRenderChildren
>     afterRender
>     finishRender
>     finishRenderItems
>     finishRender
>     finishRenderChildren
>     afterRender
>     finishRender
>     render
>     constructor
>     ctor
> <anonymous> My Project ext-all.js:20:1539234
> ExtJS 55
> onDelegatedEvent self-hosted:935
> ExtJS 31
> <anonymous> My Project
> ```

Here is the js class for the grid with the binding:

```
Ext.define(K.maintenance.classes.grid, {
extend: K.shared.classes.groupedGrid,
controller: K.maintenance.aliases.controller,
viewModel: K.maintenance.aliases.viewmodel,
requires: ['Ext.data.validator.Date'],
xtype: K.maintenance.xtypes.grid,
bind: '{store}',
tbar: {
    xtype:'toolbar',
    items: [
        {
            reference: 'print',
            iconCls:'icons-print',
        },
        '->','Start date : ',
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            reference: 'start_date',
            vtype: 'daterange',
            format: 'Y-m-d',
            bind: {
                value: '{startDate}',
                maxDate: '{endDate}'
            },
            validators: 'date'
        },'-','Stop date : ',
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            reference: 'stop_date',
            vtype: 'daterange',
            format: 'Y-m-d',
            bind: {
                value: '{endDate}',
                minDate: '{startDate}'
            },
            validators: 'date'
        }
    ] 
},
columns: {...}
viewConfig: {
    forceFit:true,
    scrollToTop: Ext.emptyFn,
    scrollOffset: 19,
    stripeRows: true
},
stateful: false,
stateId: 'tool_maintenance_status',
animCollapse: false,
});
```

Any help figuring out why that error is thrown would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach example on fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although that type of error can seem useless, it usually indicates something missing that ExtJS is expecting.

There is no `vtype: daterange` out of the box. Do you have a custom one you've implemented somewhere? If not, that could be culprit.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.VTypes.html

Another possibility is that the `validators: 'date'` config isn't doing what you expect. I've always used a function for that config property. Datefields already have some validation built in, so using the basic date validator could be redundant if not handicapping you.